# Complex regex - works in Powershell, not in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, powershell

The below code is a small portion of my code for Solarwinds to parse the output of a Netbackup command. This is fine for our Windows boxes but some of our boxes are RHEL.

I'm trying to convert the below code into something useable on RHEL 4.X but I'm running into a wall with parsing the regex. Obviously the below code has some of the characters escaped for use with Powershell, I have unescaped those characters for use with Shell.

I'm not great with Shell yet, but I will post a portion of my Shell code below the Powershell code.

```
$output = ./bpdbjobs

$Results = @()
$ColumnName = @()

foreach ($match in $OUTPUT) {
   $matches = $null
   $match -match "(?<jobID>\d+)?\s+(?<Type>(\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b\s+\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<State>(Done)|(Active)|(\w+`-\w+`-\w+))?\s+(?<Status>\d+)?\s+(?<Policy>(\w+)|(\w+`_\w+)|(\w+`_\w+`_\w+))?\s+(?<Schedule>(\b[^\d\W]+\b\-\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\-)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<Client>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Dest_Media_Svr>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Active_PID>\d+)?\s+(?<FATPipe>\b[^\d\W]+\b)?"
   $Results+=$matches
   }
```

The below is a small portion of Shell code I've written (which is clearly very wrong, learning as I go here). I'm just using this to test the Regex and see if it functions in Shell - (Spoiler alert) it does not.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

backups=bpdbjobs
results=()

for results in $backups; do

    [[ $results =~ /(?<jobID>\d+)?\s+(?<Type>(\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b\s+\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<State>(Done)|(Active)|(\w+\w+\-\w\-+))?\s+(?<Status>\d+)?\s+(?<Policy>(\w+)|(\w+\_\w+)|(\w+\_\w+\_\w+))?\s+(?<Schedule>(\b[^\d\W]+\b\-\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\-)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<Client>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Dest_Media_Svr>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Active_PID>\d+)?/ ]]

done

$results
```

Below are the errors I get.

```
 ./netbackupsolarwinds.sh: line 9: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
 ./netbackupsolarwinds.sh: line 9: syntax error near `/(?'
 ./netbackupsolarwinds.sh: line 9: `        [[ $results =~ /(?<jobID>\d+)?\s+(?<Type>(\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b\s+\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<State>(Done)|(Active)|(\w+\w+\-\w\-+))?\s+(?<Status>\d+)?\s+(?<Policy>(\w+)|(\w+\_\w+)|(\w+\_\w+\_\w+))?\s+(?<Schedule>(\b[^\d\W]+\b\-\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\-)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+(?<Client>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Dest_Media_Svr>(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(?<Active_PID>\d+)?/ ]]'
```

Comment: You may need to escape certain special characters such as ( or ) by prefixing it with \, so it would know to look for the text (Active) by writing it as \(Active\), if I understand your regex correctly.

Comment: @JCJ Escaping `(` changes its meaning from starting group to a literal `(`. For me `(` works just fine.

Comment: @JCJ As Socowi said, none of the parentheses are literal, they all denote groups within the regex.

Comment: @Djxinator This is an interesting question. However, you should boil it down. Remove all the unnecessary stuff. You only have to show us the core problem. One line of powershell code, one line of bash code, and the error message are sufficient.

Comment: In bash, replace the `/` at each end with a single quote `'` - this is not PCRE!

Comment: Quoting the regex would make everything literal. Leave it unquoted. However, you are right that `=~` does not support PCRE. `\s`, `\w` and so on do not work.

Comment: So the error is not related to the `(`? I know `'` does not fix the regex. The `/` were added in later, removing the `/` gives me identical errors.

Comment: Could you give sample of data to match?

Comment: @Bsquare `41675         Backup  Done      0     FAS999_POLICY_NAME    daily client0001      mediaserv01       5228`

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, after comments exchange.

The best way to perform your migration quickly is to use the --perl-regexp Perl compatibility option of Grep, like eventually suggested in another answer.

If you still want to perform this operation with pure Bash, you need to rewrite the regular expression accordingly, following [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: No. Escaping the parentheses will cause a syntax error "unexpected token '<'".

Comment: Even that, how is that supposed to help? The parentheses define capturing groups. Escaping them would turn them into literal parentheses, which is apparently not what the OP wants matched (since they're not escaped in the PowerShell regex either). Also, the forward slashes at beginning and end of the expression have no business being there. This is bash, not Perl. Or sed. Or awk.

Comment: True for the '/'; I then asked OP to have data sample to attempt matching test. But again I disagree about the parentheses => In my opinion, only the OUTER parentheses defines capturing groups. There is no sense to have capturing groups (inner parentheses) inside capturing groups (outer parentheses).

Comment: You're mistaken. `(?<name>(foo))` defines a named capturing group with a nested unnamed capturing group. I agree that the excessive grouping in the expression doesn't make much sense, but that doesn't change anything about how these expressions work. For reference, compare the output of `'bar' -match '(?<foo>(ba)r)'; $matches[1]` to `'bar' -match '(?<foo>bar)'; $matches[1]` and `'bar' -match '(?<foo>\(ba\)r)'; $matches[1]` in PowerShell.

Comment: You're right with the named capturing group, I updated my answer consequently.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in [regex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)(3)).

Meaning that the expression is parsed as a POSIX extended regular expression, which AFAIK does not support either named capturing groups (`(?<name>...)`) or character escapes (`\d`, `\w`, `\s`, ...).

If you want to use `[[ $var =~ expr ]]` you need to rewrite the regular expression. Otherwise use [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (which supports PCRE):

```
grep -P '(?<jobID>\d+)?\s+...' <<<$results
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers. I swapped to Grep -P to no avail, turns out the named capture groups were the problem for Grep -P.

I was also unable to figure out a way to use Grep to output the capture group matches to individual variables.

This lead me to swap over to using perl, as follows, with alterations to my regex.

`bpdbjobs | perl -lne 'print "$1" if /(\d+)?\s+((\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b\s+\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+((Done)|(Active)|(\w+\w+\-\w\-+))?\s+(\d+)?\s+((\w+)|(\w+\_\w+)|(\w+\_\w+\_\w+))?\s+((b[^\d\W]+\b\-\b[^\d\W]+\b)|(\-)|(\b[^\d\W]+\b))?\s+((\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+((\w+\.\w+\.\w+)|(\w+))?\s+(\d+)?/g'`

With `$<num>` referring to the capture group number. I can now list, display and (the important part) count the number of matches within an individual group, corresponding to the data found in each column.

Comment: `grep -P` (version 2.27 on my system) should be able to handle named capturing groups just fine. For matching, that is. It won't give you backreferences to extract submatches, though. You need something like `sed` or `awk` (or Perl or course) if you want to actually do something with the captured groups.